# Access Restful Service which is OWASP CSRFGuard protected from Different Domain

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, cross-domain, owasp

1. My application has been built using SPRING MVC and I have exposed few Restful URIs. **(Working Fine)**
   e.g - http://example.org/alert/alerts //get list of Alerts for the logged in user.
2. I have configured the application for Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) using OWASP CSRFGuard by following the link - **(Working Fine)** https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_Configuration#Overview
3. The Restful services is currently been consumed by the same application's UI without having any issues. **(Working Fine)**
   e.g - A data Grid which is part of the same WebApp is displaying list of Alerts by calling this Restful service (AJAX request)
4. **Issue**: When I try to access the same Restful services from a different domain/ Chrome Rest Client, it's doesn't return any data except for 302.
5. If I set The "unprotected pages" property in csrfguard.properties for the restful URIs, I am able to access the Restful service from RestClient/different domain.

Please suggest if I need to do any other configuration so that the same Restful services which are protected by CSRF can be accessed from a different domain/Chrome rest Client.

Comment: You may want to try out [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) instead. It offers built-in [CSRF protection support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf). It's more maintained and less cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 0):

1.if you are generating CSRF Token at server side then
   provide one get request inside that request validate session and send the created CSRF Token as hidden to client, now remaining request should be POST,PATCH,PUT or DELETE which are getting CSRF Token in every request header. 
2. if you are generating CSRF Token at client side then from first request which is authentication or authorization get the value of Token and compare it with every request in your custom filter.